# Export Data To Excel Sheet Which Already Contains Some Predefined Data And Send As Email Attachment

Tags: c#, devexpress, export, aspxgridview

Export Data From `Devexpress ASpxGridView` into a `Excel` File and that Excel File already has some of the keyfields included.

*So Data Should Be Filled in Proper Format without overwriting the existing data.*

Also the file should be opened and modified to make one of the fields as dropdownlist consisting of few predefined items.

Now after the data has been exported to excel file and operations done, this file should be send as an attachment of an email.

If any such similar requirement references you have, please do guide through.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the edit Niranjan Kala.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    EmailMessage msg = new EmailMessage();
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"c:\Test.xls", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);  
    Exporter.WriteXls(fs);
    msg.AddAttachment("c:\Test.xls");
    msg.Send();
    fs.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you to use [Epplus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/releases/view/42439) , you can get the data needed from your data source, open and add this data to your xlsx.

Comment: Here is a good example of use of the Epplus library http://zeeshanumardotnet.blogspot.com.br/2011/06/creating-reports-in-excel-2007-using.html

Comment: Thanks for your help Ewerton. But for my requirement I need to use the devexpress exporter control and then write the data in excel file and send that "generated" excel file as an attachment automatically.